# REST: Create SP List with specific URL

Tags: list, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, online

How to create SP list via REST with List Title `XYZ`, but with List URL `ZYX`?
 I.e., Title and URL being *different*.

Comment: oh damn :( , setting the url is supported in JSOM, CSOM  but not in REST.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need create your list first with **ZYX** and update it with **XYZ** like this you will have in URL **ZYX** and Title **XYZ**  .

Comment: Thank you, just giving this question a bit more time before accepting if there would be some one-request trick for this.